# Calculating change in Gibbs Free Energy for a specific type of problem

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, stoichiometry, metallurgy

Can anyone describe what is going on here?
$$Si(liq.)=Si_{(1 weight percentFe)}$$
I have come across this statement quite a few times in Metallurgical Thermodynamics.All that they ask for is change in Gibbs free energy for the process.I am completely unable to figure why this particular model is so important for a sepecific question.It would be great if someone could interpret both the analytical and the mathematical analogy to this.

Comment: It's not clear what "*Metallurgical Thermodynamics*" refers to. Please add a complete citation so that the context could be checked. Also, if $$Si(liq.)=Si(1 weight percent Fe)$$ is *exactly* how your source presents it, I'd say it's just poor formatting or the author doesn't know what they are writing about.

Comment: @andselisk This is from Gaskell.I do not know why they are not conting the space during formatting.

Comment: You may want to tinker with formatting. For instance, $$\ce{Si\textrm(liq)<=>Si{(1 \textrm{weight percent Fe})}}$$ is written as "\ce{Si\textrm(liq)<=>Si{(1 \textrm{weight percent Fe})}}"

Comment: Is it not more convenient to write : $\ce{0.99 Si(liq) + 0.01 Fe -> Si_{0.99} Fe_{0.01}}$ ?

Comment: @Maurice Correct but I feel the person wants to know why that is working

Comment: It is written in my book,"In situations in which the pure component exists in a physical state which differs from that of the solution of the Henrian standard state may be more convenient than the Raoultian standard state. Such situations include the solution of a solid in liquid solvent.The Henrian Standard Statte is obtained from consideration of Henry's law,which strictly being a limiting law obeyed by the solute B at infinite dilution."